# How to set up default background (greyed out) text for textbox in C++ Win32 GUI?

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox, default, placeholder

When creating a text box

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "EDIT", [...])
```

How to set the placeholder (default, grey) text on the background of that box, which disappears when providing some input?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After creating the edit control, send the [EM_SETCUEBANNER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761639(VS.85).aspx) message to it:

```
SendMessage(hwndEdit, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, (LPARAM)L"Default text");
```

Or use the [Edit_SetCueBannerText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761701(v=vs.85).aspx) macro:

```
Edit_SetCueBannerText(hwndEdit, L"Default text");
```

Either way, you also need to [enable Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @AFellow You need to include the `<Commctrl.h>` header.

Comment: @AFellow I tested the above code and it produces the desired behavior. When creating the Edit control pass an empty string, don't set the string.

Comment: @AFellow Your edited code produces the desired result. If you don't see the banner then your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @AFellow If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: `EM_SETCUEBANNER` was introduced in Windows XP, so you have to set `_WIN32_WINNT` to at least `0x0501` (see [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx)). Code::Blocks is known for poor defaults, so it may not set it at all.

Comment: @AFellow Chances are, your Win32 SDK is simply outdated and doesn't even have `EM_SETCUEBANNER`. If needed, simply `#define` it manually in your own code. It has a value of `0x1501`.